# How to bulk edit a metadata in a list of pages? Should I check out first?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to edit a metadata in a **list of pages** in sharepoint 2016 (or 2019 ?).

As for a classical list I tried a quick edit then change/extend = I edited the value in a cell then I drag to extend the selection to the whole column and voilà all cells have changed.
But this does not work : A popup appears asking for me to fix problems in my modifications.
There's a red exclamation dot in front of each line stating that I should check out file before I can do any modifications.

How can I proceed from there ?

PS: Text was edited to use the correct english terms rather that my translation from french.

Comment: Extract or Check-Out the file? I think you must check out the page before making changes.

Comment: I used "extract" because I made a litteral translation from my french SP ("le fichier X n'est pas extrait") but if i look at Julie_MSFT screenshot I think check out is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you occur the error as following?

[image]

If it is true, go to library settings> versioning settings to disable the check out:

[image]

If this is not feasible for you, please feel free to reply.

Comment: YES, this is the problem I'm facing. I thought of tweaking check/out after asking for help. I'm not the creator of that list but I think if c/o was activated it is because it's needed. Without it, you mean I won't be annoyed by those warnings ? Maybe I can disable co/process meta/enable co again. There are some files that are extracted by other users, I don't know what will happen if I disable/enable co

Comment: If you disable the check out, users could edit the document at the same time, normally when you check out a file from a SharePoint document library, only you can edit it.